# Prove that the set $\{\sin(x),\cos(x)\}$ is linearly independent using derivative.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence

Prove that the set $\{\sin(x),\cos(x)\}$ is linearly independent using matricies.

**Method 1**

Let $r\sin(x)+s\cos(x)=0$

If $x=0$, this means that $s=0$

If $x=\pi/2$, this means that $r=0$.

Therefore the set is linearly independent.

**Method 2 - using derivatives**

$$r\sin(x)+s\cos(x)=0 \tag 0$$ 
Differentiating once,

$$r\cos(x)-s\sin(x)=0 \tag 1$$
Differentiating again,

$$-r\sin(x)-s\cos(x)=0 \tag 2$$

Take equation $0$ and $2$ in a matrix.

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} RREF 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

So this still brings us back to our original $r\sin(x)+s\cos(x)=0$. Does this mean that it **cannot** be solved with a matrix, and we must solve it manually?

Comment: but you can use the 0th and 1th equation

Comment: you mean prove that the functions $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ and $x \mapsto \cos(x)$ are linearly independent. Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation and the differentiated equation give a nontrivial element $(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ of the kernel of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} r & s \\ -s & r \end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that the determinant of this matrix is $r^2+s^2=0$, so $r=s=0$. Note that this method proves more: that there is no interval on which the sine and cosine functions are constant multiples of one another.

Answer (score 0):

$\left\lbrace \begin{array}l r\sin(x)+s\cos(x)=0 \quad [\times \sin(x)] \\  r\cos(x)-s\sin(x)=0 \quad[\times \cos(x)]\end{array}\right. \iff \left\lbrace \begin{array}l r\sin^2(x)+s\cos(x)\sin(x)=0 \quad (1) \\  r\cos^2(x)-s\cos(x)\sin(x)=0 \quad (2)\end{array}\right.$

Then $(1)+(2)$ : $\quad r\big(\underbrace{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}_{= 1}\big)=0\iff r=0$

...same method for $s$

Answer (score -1):

Following your argument, you have two equations:
$$r\sin(x)+s\cos(x)=0 \tag 0$$
$$r\cos(x)-s\sin(x)=0 \tag 1$$
In matrix notation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}r & s\\ -s & r\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin x \\
\cos x 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
for all $x$. This implies that
$$\begin{pmatrix}r & s\\ -s & r\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
for all x and y. It follows that
$$\begin{pmatrix}r & s\\ -s & r\end{pmatrix}=0$$